# varnish.service: A process of this unit has been killed by the OOM killer

Tags: varnish

I have varnish installed on the Ubuntu server 22.04.

The environment is Php8.1 and Varnish 7.3.0.

The server has 16GB RAM.

For me the Varnish keep on crashing intermittently and I get following message.

```
:~$ sudo service varnish status
× varnish.service - Varnish Cache, a high-performance HTTP accelerator
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/varnish.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: oom-kill) since Mon 2023-11-20 13:18:05 UTC; 18s ago
   Process: 198053 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd -a :80 -a localhost:8443,PROXY -p feature=+http2 -p http_resp_hdr_len=35M -p http_resp_size=40M -p workspac>
   Main PID: 198054 (code=exited, status=64)
        CPU: 14min 39.533s

Nov 20 13:18:05    varnishd[198054]: Manager got SIGTERM
Nov 20 13:18:05    systemd[1]: varnish.service: A process of this unit has been killed by the OOM killer.
Nov 20 13:18:05    varnishd[198054]: Stopping Child
Nov 20 13:18:05    varnishd[198054]: Child (198068) died signal=9
Nov 20 13:18:05    varnishd[198054]: Child cleanup complete
Nov 20 13:18:05    varnishd[198054]: manager stopping child
Nov 20 13:18:05    varnishd[198054]: manager dies
Nov 20 13:18:05    systemd[1]: varnish.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=64/USAGE
Nov 20 13:18:05    systemd[1]: varnish.service: Failed with result 'oom-kill'.
Nov 20 13:18:05    systemd[1]: varnish.service: Consumed 14min 39.533s CPU time.
lines 1-17/17 (END)
```

I have following setting in the */etc/systemd/system/varnish.service*

```
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd \
      -a :80 \
      -a localhost:8443,PROXY \
      -p feature=+http2 \
      -p http_resp_hdr_len=35M \
      -p http_resp_size=40M \
      -p workspace_backend=40M \
      -p workspace_client=40M \
      -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
      -s malloc,512m
```

I have increased the assigned memory to Varnish and also created a swap memory

```
sudo fallocate -l 2G /swapfile
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
```

but it still crashes.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-s malloc,512m` statement limits the cache storage to 512 MB, but that doesn't mean Varnish will only consume 512 MB of RAM.

### Runtime cost

There is a runtime cost to Varnish that grows as the number of active threads increases. Each worker thread that handles a request consumes some memory. The amount is defined through the `workspace_client` runtime parameter.

### Workspace memory

If a backend request is made the `workspace_backend` value is used to set the size. There is even a `workspace_session` to set the memory used for handling new TCP connections.

Normally `workspace_client` and `workspace_backend` default to 64 KB, which means each thread can use that amount of memory.

In your case, you've set the values of `workspace_client` and `workspace_backend` extremely high. If you allow 40 MB of workspace memory, you should multiple that number with the amount of active threads to figure out how much memory Varnish will consume a the minimum.

### Threads

Run the following `varnishstat` command to figure out how many active threads you currently have:

```
varnishstat -f "MAIN.threads" -1
```

The number of threads varies between the value of the `thread_pool_min` runtime parameter and the `thread_pool_max` runtime parameter. Out of the box this number ranges between 100 and 5000. Keep in mind that there are 2 thread pools, so you have to multiple that number by 2.

If we do the math on a hypothetical use case where all threads are used, it's 40 MB times 10.000 threads. That's 390 GB.

### Conclusion

It's clear that you've set the workspace parameters too high. Based on the runtime configuration you need this to handle extremely large request and response headers.

There are 3 ways forward:

- Reduce `thread_pool_max`, but risk queueing requests when the limit has been reached
- Reduce the workspace memory size, which also means you won't be able to handle huge request/response headers
- Add a lot more memory to your server and maybe add multiple Varnish servers to distribute the load